# Show particular div on click on link for this html hierarchy

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my .html code

```
 <div class="col-2"> 
       <div class="col-content">
         <div class="lt">
           <div class="lt-img arch"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="rt">                  
                <h3>Competitve Prices</h3>
                 <p>Arch Linux 2012.12 x64</p>
                 <a href="">Read more <div class="arrow"></div></a>                   
           </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
           <div class="wholebox">
                    <ul>
                       <li>Arch Linux 2012.12 x64</li>
                        <li>Arch Linux 2012.08 x64</li>
                        <li>Arch Linux 2012.08 x86</li>
                    </ul>
           </div>
       </div>
     </div>
```

I have .js file code here ..

```
 $( ".rt a" ).click(function() {
   $( ".wholebox" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
   return false;
  });
```

**Problem** : When i click on link it show all div having class`wholebox`.In `.css` file i set property to `display:none` for this `wholebox` class.How can i show `wholebox` only for particular link with this hierarchy of `HTML` code .

Comment: One method is that i give different  `id` for all div which i want to show on click.But what if i want to show 1000 of divs.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.rt a').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.col-content').find('.wholebox').slideToggle('slow');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: for correction .     $(this).closest('.col-content').find('.wholebox').slideToggle('slow');

Comment: Sorry, I thought .lt was wrapping .wholebox

Answer (score 1):

Try sth like following:

```
 $( ".rt a" ).click(function() {
  //first look for <div class="col-content"> and find class .wholebox
   $(this).parent().parent().find(".wholebox").slideToggle( "slow" );
   return false;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Give some data-id to your  tag and map that id to your "***wholebox***" class.

Refer below code. 
Only need to collect id from  `<a href="" data-id="1">` and map it to `<div class="wholebox**1**">`

`<div class="col-2"> 
       <div class="col-content">
         <div class="lt">
           <div class="lt-img arch"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="rt">

                <h3>Competitve Prices</h3>
                 <p>Arch Linux 2012.12 x64</p>
                 <a href="" data-id="1">Read more <div class="arrow"></div></a>

           </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
           <div class="wholebox1">
                    <ul>
                       <li>Arch Linux 2012.12 x64</li>
                        <li>Arch Linux 2012.08 x64</li>
                        <li>Arch Linux 2012.08 x86</li>
                    </ul>
           </div>
       </div>
     </div>`

```
 $( ".rt a" ).click(function() {
     $( ".wholebox"+($(this).attr("data-id")) ).slideToggle( "slow" );
     return false;
  });
```

Comment: Very nice Thank you for you help but what if i have 1000 div and i already wrote .I will write `attr` for each one again ?.That's why i already mentioned with different `id` it hard to do.@kapantzak and @jyrkim answered are appreciated.Thank you  :)

Comment: No need do it manually, you can use loop counter and make it possible.